# Laravel pass variable from 1 function in controller to another one

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have 2 functions in a controller

This is the get function

```
public function getAllDept($allDEPT2)
{
    $allDEPT = Facultyform::where('Home_Department_Desc', '=', $allDEPT2)->paginate(1);

 $allDEPTs =  View::make('faculty/dept', compact('allDEPT','certifications','certifications1','advisment','facultydata','facultydata1','facultydegree','facultydegree1','commembership', 'commembership1','otherpro','otherpro1','priorteaching','priorteaching1','publication','publication1','professioncourse','professioncourse1','support','support1','otherschool','otherschool1' ));



    return $allDEPTs;
}
```

This is the post function

```
 public function getAllDept2()
 {
  if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) {
            return Response::json( array(
                'msg' => 'Unauthorized attempt to create setting'
            ) );
        }

        $fId = Input::get( 'faculty_id' );

        $faculty = Facultyform::where('File_Number', '=', $fId)
        ->get();
        if($faculty[0]['isChair'] == 'Y'){
    $allDEPT2 = $faculty[0]['Home_Department_Desc'];

    $allDEPT = Facultyform::where('Home_Department_Desc', '=', $allDEPT2)->paginate(1);
    $this->getAllDept($allDEPT2);

      $allDEPTs =  View::make('faculty/dept', compact('allDEPT','certifications','certifications1','advisment','facultydata','facultydata1','facultydegree','facultydegree1','commembership', 'commembership1','otherpro','otherpro1','priorteaching','priorteaching1','publication','publication1','professioncourse','professioncourse1','support','support1','otherschool','otherschool1' ));



    return $allDEPTs;
    }
```

I have created both routes

```
 Route::get('faculty/dept',array(
    'uses' => 'FacultyController@getAllDept'
 )); 

Route::post('faculty/dept', array(
    'as' => 'faculty/dept',
    'uses' => 'FacultyController@getAllDept2'
));
```

When the end user uses the faculty/getDept and put the id it shows the 1st item in the list utilizing the view, but when I click on the next page I get the following error
Missing argument 1 for FacultyController::getAllDept() 
If i hard code a department the pagination works but its only for the hard coded department.

I tried $this->getALLDept($allDEPT2);
I tried creating a session of the variable
I tried to make the variable global
is there something I can do in the controller to pass the variable from one function to the other function or do I do this in the route?

This is what the one of the functions look like

```
      public function getFacultyId() {
        //check if its our form
        if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) {
            return Response::json( array(
                'msg' => 'Unauthorized attempt to create setting'
            ) );
        }
       //check if its our form
        if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) {
            return Response::json( array(
                'msg' => 'Unauthorized attempt to create setting'
            ) );
        }

        $fId = Input::get( 'faculty_id' );

        $faculty = Facultyform::where('File_Number', '=', $fId)
        ->get();
        $lastNames = $faculty[0]['Last_Name'];
        $firstNames = $faculty[0]['First_Name'];

            $certCount = Certifications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)

        ->count();
        if ($certCount < 1)
        {
        $certifications1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $certifications1 = " ";
        }

        $certifications = Certifications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)

        ->get();

        $advisment = Advisment::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();

        $fsCount = $facultydata = Facultydata::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)            
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
        if ($fsCount < 1)
        {
        $facultydata1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $facultydata1 = " ";
        }
        $facultydata = Facultydata::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();

        $eduCount =  Facultydegree::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
        if ($eduCount < 1)
        {
        $facultydegree1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $facultydegree1 = " ";
        }
        $facultydegree = Facultydegree::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();

        $comCount = Commembership::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)            
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
        if ($comCount < 1)
        {
        $commembership1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $commembership1 = " ";
        }

        $commembership = Commembership::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();

        $otherCount = OtherPro::where('Last_Name', '=', $lastNames)
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
        if ($otherCount < 1)
        {
        $otherpro1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $otherpro1 = " ";
        }
        $otherpro = OtherPro::where('Last_Name', '=', $lastNames)
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();

        $ptCount = PriorTeaching::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)         
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
        if ($ptCount < 1)
        {
        $priorteaching1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $priorteaching1 = " ";
        }
        $priorteaching = PriorTeaching::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();

        $pubCount = Publications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)         
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
        if ($pubCount < 1)
        {
        $publication1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $publication1 = " ";
        }
        $publication = Publications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)          
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();
        $pcCount = ProfessionCourse::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)          
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
            if ($pcCount < 1)
        {
        $professioncourse1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $professioncourse1 = " ";
        }
        $professioncourse = ProfessionCourse::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)         
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();
        $supportCount = Support::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)          
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
            if ($supportCount < 1)
        {
        $support1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $support1 = " ";
        }
        $support = Support::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();

        $osCount = OtherSchool::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->count();
        if ($osCount < 1)
        {
        $otherschool1 = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
        $otherschool1 = " ";
        }
        $otherschool = OtherSchool::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
        ->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
        ->get();
$allviews =  View::make('faculty.faculty', compact('faculty','certifications','certifications1','advisment','facultydata','facultydata1','facultydegree','facultydegree1','commembership', 'commembership1','otherpro','otherpro1','priorteaching','priorteaching1','publication','publication1','professioncourse','professioncourse1','support','support1','otherschool','otherschool1'));
```

I was making one for each department that requested it. I had 3 (all, financial and academic)so far then it hit me to make one that each department chair can view only their department info by entering their credentials. The security works just want to pass their department to the other function

I made a variable in the controller called department

```
public function getAllDept($department){

$department = Facultyform::where('Home_Department_Desc', '=',$department)->get();
echo($department[0]['Home_Department_Desc']);
$allDEPT = Facultyform::where('Home_Department_Desc', '=',$department[0]['Home_Department_Desc'])->paginate(1);
$lastNames = $allDEPT[0]['Last_Name'];
$firstNames = $allDEPT[0]['First_Name'];

$certCount = Certifications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)

->count();
if ($certCount < 1)
{
$certifications1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$certifications1 = " ";
}

$certifications = Certifications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)

->get();

$advisment = Advisment::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();

$fsCount = $facultydata = Facultydata::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)            
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($fsCount < 1)
{
$facultydata1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$facultydata1 = " ";
}
$facultydata = Facultydata::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();

$eduCount =  Facultydegree::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($eduCount < 1)
{
$facultydegree1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$facultydegree1 = " ";
}
$facultydegree = Facultydegree::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();

$comCount = Commembership::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)            
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($comCount < 1)
{
$commembership1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$commembership1 = " ";
}

$commembership = Commembership::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();

$otherCount = OtherPro::where('Last_Name', '=', $lastNames)
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($otherCount < 1)
{
$otherpro1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$otherpro1 = " ";
}
$otherpro = OtherPro::where('Last_Name', '=', $lastNames)
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();

$ptCount = PriorTeaching::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)         
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($ptCount < 1)
{
$priorteaching1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$priorteaching1 = " ";
}
$priorteaching = PriorTeaching::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();

$pubCount = Publications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)         
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($pubCount < 1)
{
$publication1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$publication1 = " ";
}
$publication = Publications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)          
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();
$pcCount = ProfessionCourse::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)          
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($pcCount < 1)
{
$professioncourse1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$professioncourse1 = " ";
}
$professioncourse = ProfessionCourse::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)         
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();
$supportCount = Support::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)          
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($supportCount < 1)
{
$support1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$support1 = " ";
}
$support = Support::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();

$osCount = OtherSchool::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->count();
if ($osCount < 1)
{
$otherschool1 = "N/A";
}
else
{
$otherschool1 = " ";
}
$otherschool = OtherSchool::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)           
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)
->get();
$allDEPTs =  View::make('faculty/dept', compact('allDEPT','certifications','certifications1','advisment','facultydata','facultydata1','facultydegree','facultydegree1','commembership', 'commembership1','otherpro','otherpro1','priorteaching','priorteaching1','publication','publication1','professioncourse','professioncourse1','support','support1','otherschool','otherschool1' ));



return $allDEPTs;
//$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
//$last_query = end($queries);
//var_dump($last_query);
//die();
}
```

In my route I added the variable to the uri

```
//faculty get users by department//
 Route::get('faculty/dept/{department}',
    'FacultyController@getAllDept'
    );
```

When I do faculty/dept/ACDS I go get data
Here is a pic of it
[image: Working before pagination]

When I click next I get the error 
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

This is the uri I get when I click next /facultyform/faculty/dept?page=2

maybe I have to make it go /facultyform/faculty/dept/department?page2 instead?

Here is more info of the error I am getting
 GET Data
Key     Value
page    2
POST Data empty
Files empty 

Here is a working url
/facultyform/faculty/dept/Health%20Science%20and%20Technologies?page=2 

Now I just have to get the department in the url and I am done :)

Comment: from where you get faculty_id ? it is not included in the route. Do you have another get route for passing the id?

Comment: I created a route Route::post('/', array(
    'as' => 'faculty.create',
    'uses' => 'FacultyController@getID'
)); This then uses a form that gets the id

Comment: So much wrong with the flow and organization.... You are hardcoding everything.

Comment: This isn't the whole code for each function there are over 200 line each for each functions just wanted to show the concept of my functions

Comment: which laravel version you are using? seems you make things harder for you when laravel serve it in a golden plate for you.

Comment: this is laravel 4.2. It should be a simple pass variable from one function to the other and that's it. That's how regular programming works. call function1 inside function2 pass variable.

Comment: So it seems that my program is working, but when I paginate to the next item I am getting this error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Answer (score 0):

When I go to the view I am able to hardcode the department and all works Now I just need to pass the variable from the controller to the view

```
        {{ Form::open(array(
    'route' => ['faculty/dept/{department}','ACDS'],
    'method' => 'post',
    'id' => 'form-getdept-setting'
))}}

{{ Form::label( 'faculty_id', 'Faculty Id:' ) }}
{{ Form::text( 'faculty_id', '', array(
    'id' => 'faculty_id',
    'placeholder' => 'Enter Faculty Id',
    'maxlength' => 20,
    'required' => true,
) ) }}


{{ Form::submit( 'Find Information', array(
    'id' => 'btn-getdeptsetting',
) ) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

```
public function getAllDept2($department){
if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) {
return Response::json( array(
'msg' => 'Unauthorized attempt to create setting'
) );
}

$fId = Input::get( 'faculty_id' );

$faculty = Facultyform::where('File_Number', '=', $fId)
->get();
if($faculty[0]['isChair'] == 'Y'){
$department = Facultyform::where('Home_Department_Desc', '=',$department)->get();
$department2 = $department[0]['Home_Department_Desc'];
$allDEPT2 = $faculty[0]['Home_Department_Desc'];
dd($department);
$allDEPT = Facultyform::where('Home_Department_Desc', '=', $allDEPT2)->paginate(1);
$this->getAllDept($allDEPT2);
$lastNames = $allDEPT[0]['Last_Name'];
$firstNames = $allDEPT[0]['First_Name'];
$certCount = Certifications::where('Last_Name','=',$lastNames)
->where('First_Name','=',$firstNames)

->count();
...
$allDEPTs =  View::make('faculty/dept',compact('allDEPT','certifications','certifications1'
,'advisment','facultydata','facultydata1','facultydegree','facultydegree1','commembership', 
'commembership1','otherpro','otherpro1','priorteaching','priorteaching1','publication'
,'publication1','professioncourse','professioncourse1','support','support1','otherschool'
,'otherschool1'));
return $allDEPTs;
/* $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
var_dump($last_query);
die(); */
}
else{
return Redirect::to('/');
}
}
```